Convergence of vector sequence when inner product converges to $0$
Let $d\in \mathbb N_{\ge 2}$, $(v_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of vectors in $\mathbb R^d$. If $\inf\limits_{N\in \mathbb N} \sup\limits_{i>j>N} v_i\cdot v_j =0$, does $v_i$ converge to $0$?
I believe that it's true, but I can't sort out the proof.

I've proven that, if $d=2$ and $\inf\limits_{N\in \mathbb N} \sup\limits_{i>j>N} |v_i\cdot v_j| =0$, then the sequence converges, by:
Rewrite the statement as $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in \mathbb N$, $\forall i>j>N$, $|v_i\cdot v_j|<\epsilon$.

If $\exists N\in \mathbb N$, $\forall i>j>N$, $v_i/\!/v_j$, then there's at most one $k>N$ s.t. $|v_k|>\sqrt \epsilon$. $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists k, \forall i>k, |v_i|<\sqrt \epsilon$.

If $\forall N\in \mathbb N$, $\exists i>j>N$, $v_i\backslash\!\!\!\!{/\!/}v_j$, then $v\mapsto \max(v\cdot v_i,v\cdot v_j)$ is a norm. $B(0,\epsilon)$ is a bounded parallelogram. $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists i\in \mathbb N$, $v_{i+1,\ldots}$ is in this parallelogram.


What should I do to next?

Suppose that the sequence $(v_i)$ does not converge to zero. Then
$$
\lim\sup_{i\to\infty} |v_i|=a\in (0,\infty].
$$
After passing to a subsequence, we may assume that
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} |v_i|=a>0.
$$
Consider the sequence of normalized vectors
$$
u_i= v_i/|v_i|\in S^{d-1}.
$$
After passing to a further subsequence $(v_{i_k})$ (using  compactness of the unit sphere), we get
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} u_{i_k}=u\in S^{d-1}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \angle (v_{i_k}, u)=0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} |v_{i_k}|=a\in (0, \infty]. 
$$
By applying the triangle inequality for the angular distance, we obtain
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sup_{k> l\ge N} \angle(v_{i_k}, v_{i_l})=0,
$$
and, thus,
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sup_{k> l\ge N} \langle v_{i_k}, v_{i_l}\rangle = a^2\ne 0.
$$
This is a contradiction.

Doesn't the compactness argument require assuming the sequence is bounded?

The sequence of normalized vectors will be bounded. @MathematicsStudent1122
